# How can i insert page in ionic 3 segment layout

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

```
This is my app with Tabs layout
```

[image]

> Once i click on profile tab i push a page say Profile.ts  which contains ion-segment in its own template Profile.html

Profile.html

```
<ion-content>
  <ion-segment [(ngModel)]="whichPage" color="primary">
  <ion-segment-button style="font-size: 11px" value="Personal">
    Personal
  </ion-segment-button>
</ion-segment>

<div [ngSwitch]="whichPage">
 <ion-list *ngSwitchCase="'Personal'">
 <ion-item>
   **HERE HOW CAN I DISPLAY ANOTHER PAGE WHICH I HAVE CREATED USING IONIC 
   GENERATE PAGE Personal**
 </ion-item>
</div>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: You wont be able to display an entire page but you can set a _component_

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You wont be able to display an entire page but you can set a component. This is because a particular page *can only have one `ion-content` tag*.

You will have to remove the header, footer and content parent tags from profile.
You can have the profile content within `Profile.html`. and then use it within your segment as a Child component as:

```
<ion-list *ngSwitchCase="'Personal'">
 <ion-item>
   <PersonalComponent></PersonalComponent>
 </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

Comment: This works fine but page events such as ionViewWillEnter, ionViewDidEnter not working for Component. Any solution?