# How to create scrollable ion-tab in ionic 3

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic-native, hybrid, ionic-view

How to create scrollable ion-tab in ionic 3.
I need horizontal scroll ion-tab options and indicator.I tried below links for implementation this feature but still not found any solution :

[How can i insert page in ionic 3 segment layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44630038/how-can-i-insert-page-in-ionic-3-segment-layout)

https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/hiding-and-showing-list-items-in-ionic/46920

[Ionic - Horizontal scroll tab for Categories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45157896/ionic-horizontal-scroll-tab-for-categories)

If I am using segment then whole all segment class need to implement at one place but I want to implement all page code at different page not at one page.

Comment: Any member have got any solution ?